# Vue - Custom component parent - child communication not working

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I'm currently learning vue.js and i'm struggling with the communication between parent and child components.

I'm trying to build two components (in separate files), a "accordion-container" and "accordion". The idea ist to then use them something like that on pages:

```
<accordion-container>
  <accordion :title="'Accordion n1'">Insert HTML code here</accordion>
  <accordion :title="'2nd Accordion'">Insert HTML code here</accordion>
</accordion-container>
```

Code for the container:

```
<template @closeAccordions="closeOtherAccordions">
    <div class="accordion-container"><slot></slot></div>
</template>
<script>

export default {
    props:['title'],
    methods:{
        closeOtherAccordions: function(){
            console.log('Emit from child component received')
        },
    },
    data: function() {
        return {
            
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Code for the accordions:

```
<template>
    <div class="accordion" v-bind:class="{ open: isOpen }" :data-title="title">
        <div class="title" @click="toggleAccordion">
            <p>{{title}}</p>
        </div>
        <div class="content"><slot></slot></div>
    </div>
</template>
<script>

export default {
  props:['title'],
  methods:{
      toggleAccordion: function(){
          this.isOpen = !this.isOpen
          this.$emit('closeAccordions')
      }
  },
  data: function() {
      return {
          isOpen: false
      }
  },
  
};
</script>
```

On the accordion i'm trying to emit "closeAccordions" (with the method toggleAccordion())
Then on the parent (accordion-container) i'd like to "listen" for that emit (with :closeAccordions="closeOtherAccordions"), and then execute a method on the parent.

But that method does not get called when i click the accordions.

Is my idea even possible? (Open to other ideas :) )

Comment: I don't believe that'll be possible.  You could use the [provide/inject](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#provide-inject) functionality to have your parent component provide a method that the child component can call.

Comment: Thanks @StevenB. i'll take a look at it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't work that way. The parent component cannot directly communicate to any components rendered within its slots via events, props, or by any other means that can only be achieved at the site where the slot contents are directly rendered (the container component doesn't control this).

When you are designing a component and you put a `<slot>` in the template, all you are doing is designating an insertion point within the template that users of the component can inject their own content.

You have 4 options:

1. (Advanced) Write the render function by hand and override the rendered slot vnodes to inject your own event listeners, props, etc.
2. Expose an API using scoped slots where you pass some data or methods to the slot which the user of the component would have to hook up in order for the component to operate correctly. Users of the component would have to remember to hook everything up correctly between the container and each accordion, so it's not ideal in this situation, but in general it is useful when you want to leave some of the functionality up to the user as to how the parent and children should operate.
3. Don't use events to communicate between the container and accordions, instead the accordions can call methods on the container directly via `this.$parent`.
4. Use provide/inject to allow the container to provide an API that each accordion can inject and use.

(3) is the recommended approach in this situation. The container and accordion components should be tightly coupled here. The accordion component can (and should) only be used directly within the container component, so it's OK if they communicate directly like that.

```js
// Change this
this.$emit('closeAccordions')

// To this
this.$parent.closeOtherAccordions()
```

For more complicated components, (4) might be better.